# How to use primary domain for Openid authentication in Identity Server 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, identityserver3

1. xyz.com
2. yzx.com
3. zxy.com

I have these domains and running identity server 4 application with AuthO Openid connections. My primary domain is `xyz.com`, so if user login by using another domain like `yzx.com`, it will redirect to my primary domain call back path only after AuthO successful login. Because I have registered call back path of my primary domain only in the all the running domains.

See the example below:

```
var primaryBrandOpenIdRedirectURL = SharedResourceConstants.HyperText + primaryBrandHostUrl + pathBase.GetPathBase(HttpContext) + sso.RedirectPath;

var openIdOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
                {
                    ClientId = rijndaelEncryption.Decrypt(sso.ClientId),
                    ClientSecret = rijndaelEncryption.Decrypt(sso.ClientSecret),
                    Authority = sso.Authority,
                    SignInScheme = 
                     IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
                    ForwardSignOut = sso.ForwardSignOut,

                    // Call back path should be unique.
                    CallbackPath = new PathString(sso.RedirectPath),
                };

if (!organization.IsDefaultBrand)
{
    openIdOptions.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
                        {
                            ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = primaryBrandOpenIdRedirectURL;
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    };
}
```

This working fine in two different localhost ports but in staging facing below issue.

> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
>
> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.d__12.MoveNext() at offset 1286
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at offset 17
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) at offset 39
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) at offset 46
> at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.d__6.MoveNext() at offset 437
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at offset 17
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) at offset 39
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext() at offset 953
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at offset 17
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) at offset 39
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) at offset 46 ```

Comment: do you use HTTPS locally? what about staging?

Comment: yes I am using https://localhost:44339 only aslo staging like  https://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

The problem Correlation failed is a common error when the OpenIDConnect authentication middleware receives a callback from the IdentityServer that it did not expect.

The client that made the initial authentication request must also be the one that the browser is redirected back to after the user logs in and gives consent. (ie the same domain must be used)

I guess each client domain need to be registered in the valid redirect URL's
like

RedirectUris = new List()
{
"https://xyz1.com/signin-oidc",
"https://xyz2.com/signin-oidc",
"https://xyz3.com/signin-oidc"
};

You should also examine and make sure so that the ReturnUrl sent to IdentityServer is the true domain of the client, so that the browser can find its way back to it when it is done with the consent part.

https://localhost:6001/Account/Login?**ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dauthcodeflowclient_dev%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5001%252Fsignin-oidc**%26response_type%3Dcode%26prompt%3Dconsent%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%2520offline_...

Comment: Okay then, How to use the single domain callback path for all the domains ? is this possible?

Comment: Only the client making the initial request must also complete the authentication process